# OpenCV frame delayed

Tags: opencv, frame

I have a simple code whereby upon user input, the camera would capture an image. Here's the code:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    cvWaitKey(0);                         //wait for input then take picture
    Mat grabbed = cam1.CamCapture();
    Image[i].setImage(grabbed.clone());
    imshow("picture", Image[i].getImage());
    cvWaitKey(1);
}
```

The problem is where upon displaying the images, Image[i] is displaying the picture meant for Image[i-1].

I do not understand what seems to be problem as I would thought that upon entering the loop, I would have to press a key, then the camera would capture a picture and store it into the first object, Image[0] and the process is repeated for 4 times. This however does not seem to be the case.

I have a workaround at the moment which is using nested loops.
    int k;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        cvWaitKey(0);                         //wait for input then take picture
        for (int k=0;i<5;k++){
             Mat grabbed = cam1.CamCapture();
             Image[i].setImage(grabbed.clone());
        }
        imshow("picture", Image[i].getImage());
        cvWaitKey(1);
    }

This however does not seem to be an efficient manner. I think the issue may be due to buffer issue but I am not too sure.

Please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to a do while loop

int i=0;

```
do {
    cvWaitKey(0);                         //wait for input then take picture
    Mat grabbed = cam1.CamCapture();
    Image[i].setImage(grabbed.clone());
    imshow("picture", Image[i].getImage());
    cvWaitKey(1);
}while ( i<4; i++)
```

This is untested

Comment: may I ask what is the reasoning for doing so?

Comment: That way you are running the code at least once with i = 0. then incrementing.